# Why can't the results display on my tkinter window?

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, thread-safety

I am trying to create a pomodoro clock that helps with time management. I tried to write the code using some for loops and encapsulating those loops in methods so that I can call those methods by clicking some buttons on the tkinter display window that I named **window**. Initially, my approach involved only using the methods but the display did not respond to my input so instead I came up with the idea of using threads (two threads to be precise- one that would notify you to work and another to take a break) so that I can display the information one after the other with clear distinction between both outputs and this did work, but I also wanted to add a functionality that would let the whole process start from the beginning and this is what my code looked like:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from threading import Thread

class Work(Thread):
   def run(self):
         print("!!!!")
         timer.config(text="Work",fg=GREEN)
         start=int(time())
         end=int(time())
         while end-start<3:
           end=time()

         Break().run()



array=[1]

class Break(Thread):
   def run(self):
      print("$$$$$$    ")
      timer.config(text="Break",fg=PINK)
      test=Frame(width = 100,height=50,bg=YELLOW)
      test.grid(row=3,column=1)
      Label(test,text="✔", font=(FONT_NAME, 12, "bold"), bg=YELLOW, fg=GREEN,padx=3).pack(in_=test,side=LEFT)

      start = int(time())
      end = int(time())
      while end - start < 1:
        end = time()


      array[0]+=1

def start_countdown():
  for i in range(4):
    print("Ok")
    print(i)
    Work().start()
    if i == 3:
      return "exit"
  beginning()




# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
def beginning():
  global window
  window=Tk(className="Pomodoro")
  window.title("Pomodoro")

  window.config(pady=50,padx=100,bg=YELLOW)
  global timer
  timer=Label(text="Timer",font=(FONT_NAME,50,"bold"),bg=YELLOW,foreground=GREEN)
  timer.grid(row=0,column=1)
  canvas=Canvas(width=200,height=223,bg=YELLOW,highlightthickness=0)
  counter=PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
  canvas.create_image(100,100,image=tomato)
  canvas.create_text(100,120,text="00:00",fill="white",font=(FONT_NAME,35,"bold"))
  canvas.grid(row=1,column=1)
  start=Button(text="Start",highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0,command=start_countdown)
  start.grid(row=2,column=0)
  end=Button(text="Reset",highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0)
  end.grid(row=2,column=6)

  window.mainloop()

beginning()
```

Here my main function is **beginning()** and I want it to start the process all over again once it has finished running and the reason my code has random print statements with symbols is for debugging purpose and apparently the debugging checks out and it is printing the symbols the way I want it to - one after the other properly. The only problem I am struggling with right now is that the Window doesn't seem to change in between Work state and Break state. It just changes from Work to Break only once although I want it to do this for every iteration in the for loop. Although I have to mention that, my code gives satisfactory result if I put the for loop inside the Work.run() method, which looks something like this:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
from threading import Thread

   class Work(Thread):
   def run(self):
       for i in range(4):
         print("!!!!")
         timer.config(text="Work",fg=GREEN)
         start=int(time())
         end=int(time())
         while end-start<3:
           end=time()

         Break().run()
         if i == 3:
             return "exit"



array=[1]

class Break(Thread):
   def run(self):
     
      print("$$$$$$    ")
      timer.config(text="Break",fg=PINK)
      test=Frame(width = 100,height=50,bg=YELLOW)
      test.grid(row=3,column=1)
      Label(test,text="✔", font=(FONT_NAME, 12, "bold"), bg=YELLOW, fg=GREEN,padx=3).pack(in_=test,side=LEFT)

      start = int(time())
      end = int(time())
      while end - start < 1:
        end = time()
      

      array[0]+=1

def start_countdown():

    print("Ok")

    Work().start()
    beginning()
# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
def beginning():
  global window
  window=Tk(className="Pomodoro")
  window.title("Pomodoro")

  window.config(pady=50,padx=100,bg=YELLOW)
  global timer
  timer=Label(text="Timer",font=(FONT_NAME,50,"bold"),bg=YELLOW,foreground=GREEN)
  timer.grid(row=0,column=1)
  canvas=Canvas(width=200,height=223,bg=YELLOW,highlightthickness=0)
  tomato=PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
  canvas.create_image(100,100,image=tomato)
  canvas.create_text(100,120,text="00:00",fill="white",font=(FONT_NAME,35,"bold"))
  canvas.grid(row=1,column=1)
  start=Button(text="Start",highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0,command=start_countdown)
  start.grid(row=2,column=0)
  end=Button(text="Reset",highlightthickness=0,borderwidth=0)
  end.grid(row=2,column=6)

  window.mainloop()






beginning()
```

But the only problem with this version is that the code creates two windows(instances). My question is, how can I fix this so that I can see the output for every iteration in correct order every time and also be able to rerun the whole thing after finishing the iteration? And, how can I restart the whole process (at the end) properly and automatically after the work and break threads have finished the for loop iteration?

**P.S. I just want to say I know I can solve everything by using the `update()` method like `window.update()` but I just wanted to see how I can solve this problem using threads since I want to understand how threads and processes work (starting, quitting and their interaction with the main loop thread)**

Comment: Where is FONT_NAME? Change this YELLOW to 'yellow;

Comment: What is this? timer.config(text="Work",fg='green') The timer is not defined.

Comment: `Break.run()` should be `Break().start()` instead.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Sorry I didn't post the whole code but I do have constants that represent color codes. For example, PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"

Comment: @toyotaSupra timer is set to global. If you noticed in my first set of code I did set timer to global so timer is already defined in the UI Setup section of my code.

Comment: @acw1668 If I use ```Break.start()``` this version doesn't give me the desired output. It will just display the changes for Break once instead of displaying it for every iteration.

Comment: `Break().run()` will execute `run()` in the main thread, but `Break().start()` will execute `run()` in a child thread.  Since `Break` is inherited from `Thread`, `Break().start()` is the correct way to start the task in a child thread.  If it does not work the way you want, you need to redesign your logic.

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, you are right I think. But the problem is once i start the thread I can't loop on it unless I terminate the thread and restart it again. Do you know how I can do this?